# Can requirejs optimizer work with relative paths?

Tags: requirejs, requirejs-optimizer

[Here is a sample application demonstrating the issue](https://github.com/togakangaroo/rjs-blues) (sorry no fiddle since it's about r.js which is node based)

I can't get the requirejs optimizer to work properly with relative paths.

my web app has the following directories

- app

  - index.html - includes requirejs, main.js, then `require(['plugins'])` (standard multipage setup)
  - scripts

    - main.js - bootstraps requirejs, sets baseUrl to /scripts
    - plugins.js - references and exposes modules from app-plugins. References via `../app-plugins/a.js`
  - app-plugins

    - a.js

everything works fine in the non-optimized version (run a webserver at app, open console and navigate to the index page).

Optimizing, however, gives me an error because of the `../` in plugins.js. To see this cd to the optimization directory and run `node .\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js -o .\build.json`. The error will be

```
W:\temp\requireop\optimization [master]> .\Build-RequireJs.ps1

Tracing dependencies for: main

Tracing dependencies for: plugins
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'W:\temp\requireop\build\app-plugins\a.js'
In module tree:
    plugins

Error: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'W:\temp\requireop\build\app-plugins\a.js'
In module tree:
    plugins

    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following changes and it worked:

- `main.js`:

  ```
  baseUrl: 'scripts'
  ```

  In the general case paths are case sensitive; also better not to include the leading slash.
- `optimization/build.json` becomes:

  ```
  {
      appDir: '../app',
      baseUrl: 'scripts',
      dir: '../build',
      modules: [ // the same
      ]
  }
  ```

  You can find the details [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jrburke/r.js/master/build/example.build.js), but some explanations:

  1. `appDir` lets r.js know where the sources are. I *believe* this also makes r.js know how to handle relative paths - not quite sure though.
  2. Then `baseUrl` becomes relative to the `appDir`.
  3. And the `dir` is where the output goes, it will also copy files found in your `appDir` in there.

This process *overwrites* files in `/build/`.